# Why Spring MVC get 404?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring MVC app. I get HTTP status 404 the report. Help me fix this issue. Thank You.

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message /WEB-INF/users_view.jsp
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M26

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showUsers(ModelMap model) {
        return "users_view";
    }
}
```

Project structure:

[image]

My `web.xml`:

```
<display-name>User</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Process application servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And `applicationContext.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.pravvich" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `jsp` is under `WEB-INF/view` and `InternalResourceViewResolver` prefix points to `/WEB-INF/`, you have a 404 error. To fix, change the prefix to  `/WEB-INF/view/`.

Answer (score 3):

in dispatcher servlet you have provided path `/WEB-INF/` but in application it is `WEB-INF/view/`

So changing it inside dispatcher servlet to `/WEB-INF/view/` will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Problem with InternalViewResolver

> Solution 1:  Change Prefix /WEB-INF/ to /WEB-INF/view
>
> Solution 2: While returning String from controller change “users_view”
>   to  “/view/users_view”

If you are starting new project using spring mvc try java based configuration 
refer [Spring mvc hello world example](http://java.candidjava.com/tutorial/Spring-mvc-hello-world-example.htm)